# Can もの be replaced with の when it is used to mean "thing"?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, nominalization

I'm confused about the use of the first (bold) の in this sentence:

> 「先によそへ贈る**の**を買うのっ」

I'm happy with the use of の as a nominaliser, but if I use it like that I get:

> Before that, I will buy "giving a gift" somewhere else.

You can't buy "giving a gift". I would be happy if the sentence were

> 先によそへ贈る**もの**を買うのっ。
>   Before that, I will buy a thing to give as a gift somewhere else.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: [補文標識「の」「こと」「もの」の使い分けについて](http://www.lib.tezuka-gu.ac.jp/kiyo/nTEZUKAYAMAGAKUIN-UNI/n8PDF/n8Kawagoe.pdf), [「の、こと、もの」の使い分け](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/b47082010740be1e650e9a70.html)

Comment: @broccoliforest I checked your second link (way above my current standard). Summary: もの=concrete, の=abstract. の can replace a noun representing a concrete thing once established. With the latter I could translate as "Before that I will buy **the one I'm giving as a present** elsewhere. Now I realise I haven't given enough context, but she was going to buy a present in her current location too, so this translation doesn't quite work.

Comment: Ah, it's not that. She doesn't say "elsewhere". 先に means "first, on ahead".

Comment: @broccoliforest Well then, I'm stumped. I know no meaning of よそ other than "elsewhere"  and I can't see a substantial difference between "before that" and "first/ahead". Please help.

Comment: @user3856370 It doesn't say "Summary: もの=concrete, の=abstract".

Comment: @user3856370 Okay, now I know. よそ doesn't only mean "elsewhere" but "other people (that belong other group than you)". For some reason I kept overlooking you didn't translate the word as it should be. In this sentence, よそへ is qualifying 贈る but not 買う, as it's impossible for 買う to take へ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That の is a pronoun that indicates something aforementioned in the context. (よそ means a family that is not your own or your relatives.)

"I'll buy **one** to give to other families first".